# Mongoose : TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined (EJS / mongoDB)

Tags: node.js, ejs, mongoose-schema

```
    >[nodemon] starting `node app.js`  
    >(node:10176) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'MongoError' of module exports inside circular dependency  
    >(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)  
    >Server started on port 3000  
    >(node:10176) DeprecationWarning: Listening to events on the Db class has been deprecated and will be removed in the next major version.  
    
    >events.js:292  
    >>      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event  
          ^
    
    >TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined  
    >>   at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\app.js:82:23  
    
    >>   at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all  together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4866:16  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4889:21  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4399:11  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\kareem\index.js:136:16  
    >>    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)  
    >> Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4868:13  
    >>    at C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Full-Stack-Developer\EJS\putting all together\toDoList\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16  
        [... lines matching original stack trace ...]  
    >>    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:75:11)  
    >[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

**I suspect that items & lists collection of todolistDB are being undefined in the app.js. Not able to understand from where it is being broken. Since items collection is undefined, push property is not being implemented. I am using ejs for the body, mongoose for the mongoDB connnection. I am attaching three parts of code below, related to it:
1. ejs
2. app.js
3. package.json**

```
 

 <%- include("header") -%>
    
      <div class="box" id="heading">
        <h1> <%= listTitle %> </h1>
      </div>
    
      <div class="box">
        <% newListItems.forEach(function(item){ %>
          <form action="/delete" method="post">
            <div class="item">
              <input 
                type="checkbox" 
                onchange="this.form.submit()" 
                value="<%= item._id %>" 
                name="checkbox"
              >
              <p><%=  item.name  %></p>
            </div>
            <input 
              type='hidden' 
              name="listName"
              value="<%= listTitle %>" 
            >
          </form>
        <% }); %>
    
    
          <form 
            class="item" 
            action="/" 
            method="post"
          >
            <input 
              type="text" 
              name="newItem" 
              placeholder="New Item" 
              autocomplete="off"
            >
            <button 
              type="submit" 
              name="list" 
              value=" <%= listTitle %> "
            >+</button>
          </form>
      </div>
    
    <%- include("footer") -%>
```

**In the above file, from the button, I am indenting to submit action on + sign, which is nested inside the form tags, while form is routing towards post method "/", so I will attach the app.js related file below:**

```
        const express = require("express");
        const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
        const mongoose = require("mongoose");
        const _ = require('lodash');
        
        const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");
        var today = date.getDate();
        
        const app = express();
        
        app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
        
        app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        app.use(express.static("public"));
        
        mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/todolistDB", {
          useNewUrlParser: true, 
          useUnifiedTopology: true,
          useFindAndModify: false,
          useCreateIndex : true
        });  //useNewUrlParser: true is used for avoiding the deprecation warning
        
        
        const itemsSchema = {
          name: String 
        };
        
        const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);  
        
        const item1 = new Item({name: "Hey, today's do list."});
        const item2 = new Item({name: "Hit the + button to add a new item"});
        const item3 = new Item({name: "<= Hit this checkbox to delete an item."});
        const defaultItems = [item1, item2, item3];
        
        const listSchema = {
          name: String,
          items: [itemsSchema]
        };
        
        const List = mongoose.model('List', listSchema);
        
        
        app.get("/", function(req, res) {
          Item.find({}, function(err, foundItems){
            console.log(foundItems);
            if (foundItems.length === 0){
              Item.insertMany(defaultItems, function(err){
                if (err){
                  console.log(err);
                } else {
                  console.log("Successfully saved the default items to DB.");  
                } 
                res.redirect("/");
              });
            } else{
            res.render("list", {
                listTitle: today, 
                newListItems: foundItems
            });
            }
          });
        });
        
        app.post("/", function(req, res){
          const itemName = req.body.newItem;
          const item = new Item( { name: itemName } );
          const listName = req.body.list;
        
          if (listName === today){
            item.save();
            res.redirect("/");
          } else {
             List.find({name : listName }, function(err, foundList){
              if (err){
                console.log(err);
              } else { 
              foundList.items.push(Item);            // error is indicated on this line as (app.js:82:23)
              foundList.save();
              res.redirect('/' + listName);
              }
            });
        
          }
        });
        
        app.post("/delete", function(req, res){
          const checkedItemId = req.body.checkbox;
          const listName = req.body.listName;
          if(listName === today){
            Item.findByIdAndRemove(checkedItemId, function(err){
              if(!err){
                console.log("successfully removed the checked item from the item list!!!");
                res.redirect("/");
              } 
            });
          } else {
            List.findOneAndUpdate({name: listName}, {$pull : {_id : checkedItemId}}, function(err){
              if(!err){
                res.redirect('/' + listName);
              }
            });
          }
          
        });
        
        
        app.get('/:customListName', function(req,res){
          const customListName = _.capitalize(req.params.customListName);
        
          List.findOne({name : customListName}, function(err, foundList){
            if(!err){
              if (!foundList){
                console.log("data doesn't exist");
                // create new list
                const list = new List({
                  name: customListName,
                  items: defaultItems
                }); 
                list.save();
                res.redirect('/' + customListName);
              } else {
                console.log('the searched data exist in the mongoDB');
                // show the existing list
                res.render('list', {
                  listTitle: foundList.name, 
                  newListItems: foundList.items
                });
              }
            } else {
              console.log(err);
            }
          });  
        });
        
        
        app.get("/about", function(req, res){
          res.render("about");
        });
        
        app.listen(3000, function() {
          console.log("Server started on port 3000");
        });
```

**Also package.json below :**

```
        {
          "name": "todolist-v1",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "description": "To do list app by EJS, backend API, MongoDB database",
          "main": "app.js",
          "scripts": {
            "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
            "start": "node app.js"
          },
          "author": "Clinto",
          "license": "ISC",
          "dependencies": {
            "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
            "ejs": "^2.6.1",
            "express": "^4.17.1",
            "lodash": "^4.17.21",
            "mongoose": "^5.11.17"
          }
        }
```

**Please help me to debug the code.**

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share what you've done so far in your attempt to debug the code?

From what I can see, the good starting point might be your mongoose schemas.

You are not calling `new Schema()`, nor you're defining custom `_id` property on your own, and according to mongoose docs, mongoose will refuse to save a document that doesn't have an `_id` property.

Example of suggested fix:

```
const itemsSchema = new Schema({
      name: String 
    });
```

or

```
    const itemsSchema = {
          _id: Number,
          name: String 
        };
```

and then within your code:

```
    // Please note that custom _id in this code is just an example, and it would be 
    // terrible practice to use in your code. 
    const item1 = new Item({_id: 123456789, name: "Hey, today's do list."});
```

Comment: Thank you for replying on this query. As per your suggestions, I tried doing both, but the error is still there. What I have implemented is : `` const { Schema } = mongoose;  const itemsSchema = new Schema({
  name: String 
}); ``   I added the _id for testing, but error was still there. By default, Mongoose adds an _id property to our schemas. Which in turn adds automatically new _id of type ObjectId to our document. What i learnt from : https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html   I tried debugging by changing many parameters, since it didn't worked out, I deleted brought back to ground zero.

Comment: Yes, mongoose by default adds _id property to documents when you are calling new Schema constructor when defining your schema.

Comment: If documents in DB actually exist and mongoose isn't the issue, I'd focus on app.post('/') route where error occured. Did you check if you are actually receiving data from ejs and that it's not actually undefined (focus on req.body.list)?  If that works, next I'd check if foundList in callback is not undefined and returns the expected value.

Comment: Also, it's important to remember that List.find will always return an array, which means you're trying to access property of the array, which will return undefined.  Therefore it might be the source of your error. Your possible fixes in that case would be either doing  foundList[0].items.push or using List.findOne what makes much more sense based on your code and you don't need to do any changes in your callback.

Comment: I found the issue, by doing console.log( itemName, item, listName, foundList); inside app.post( '/',  where value of foundList is null)  from List.find({name : listName }, function(err, foundList) . That's why not able to save() or push(). At the same time app.get('/', is able to do list.save() successfully) @niko nikic Result of console.log : (test add { _id: 6058562ddb96b030fcddc85e, name: 'test add' }  Clintoayamkudi  null)